# XFS Inaccessibility - Can not open directory '.': Input/output error

Tags: partitioning, nfs, xfs

In two VMs, the partition (LVM) those were mounted, currently went into an inaccessible state.
It's showing I/O error while trying to get inside the partition. Furthermore, it has been observed that the logical volume group is associated with the mount
point is not present, but the /dev/sda health is fine at SAN level.
UUID using which the partition entry is present in the /etc/fstab, that UUID itself doesn't exist now once with are checking this with the blkid.

We have executed the xfs_repair as well on the partition but that didn't work. We're getting an error - found candidate secondary superblock.
unable to verify superblock, continuing